# How to convert this pyspark binary column to string?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Pyspark dataframe:

```
df = spark.sql("select unhex('0A54C9E024AA62F9EF8BE39231782F9240B51CFB82D1CF7586F734EE07B51086') as db_key")
```

As you can see, it has only one column "db_key" with only one value: the result of performing the operation `unhex` over this token `0A54C9E024AA62F9EF8BE39231782F9240B51CFB82D1CF7586F734EE07B51086`. If I execute `display` over the previous dataframe, I get the following result:

```
display(df)
```

[image]

But if I execute `show()` I get this result:

```
df.show()
```

[image]

I want to obtain the same string I obtain with `display` but using `show()`. I tried casting like this, but the result is not what I want:

```
df = spark.sql("select cast(unhex('0A54C9E024AA62F9EF8BE39231782F9240B51CFB82D1CF7586F734EE07B51086') AS STRING) as db_key")
df.show()
```

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you see an `=` (equal) sign at the end, it is probably base64 related.
Fortunately, there is a built-in function [`base64`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.base64) for that in Spark :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df.withColumn("db_key_str", F.base64(F.col("db_key"))).show()
+--------------------+--------------------+
|              db_key|          db_key_str|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[0A 54 C9 E0 24 A...|ClTJ4CSqYvnvi+OSM...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```